# Is there a Nativescript TabViewItem tap event?

Tags: nativescript, tabview

I'm using Nativescript 4.1 with a `TabView` that has `androidTabsPosition="bottom"` to make it look the same on iOS and Android.

One of the `TabViewItem` has sub-pages that are accessible through buttons, so the navigation looks like:

- TabViewItem 1 shows view 1
- TabViewItem 2 shows Button 1 and Button 2

  - Click on Button 1 shows view 2.1
  - Click on Button 2 shows view 2.2

With iOS, when the view is in view 2.1, and I click the TabViewItem 2, it puts me back in the overview with the two buttons, which is very nice.

However, under Android nothing happens when I click the TabViewItem 2, it stays in view 2.1.

Is there a way to get the iOS behaviour under Android?

Comment: Which flavour you are using for development? How do you navigate?

Comment: I'm using 'nativescript-core' according to https://www.nativescript.org/blog/structuring-your-pages-sidedrawers-and-tabviews-with-nativescript-4.0 

the TabViewItem2 with the buttons is handmade and uses `args.view.page.frame.navigate` to go to view2.1 when the button1 is pressed.

Comment: Can you create a playground example of what you have described which makes it easy to debug and track the issue?